# Python: How to investigate _name_, _str_, _dict_, _doc_ on my object or my function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I read a lot about this, but all the explanations were implemented on a python class (using self). But I do not want to use a class for now. Since everything in python is an object, I just want to create an object then understand how to use the bellow ( I am not sure what are their names) on my object and what should I expect as an output:

```
__name__
__str__
__repr__
__dict__
__doc__
```

Comment: Those are double underscores (e.g, `__name__`) I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are class attributes, not object attributes, so

```
x = 1
print(x.__name__)
```

will give an `AttributeError`, but the following won't:

```
print(int.__name__)
print(int.__str__)
print(int.__repr__)
print(int.__dict__)
print(int.__doc__)
```

Output (TL;DR):

```
int
<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'int' objects>
<slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'int' objects>
{'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'int' objects>, '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'int' objects>, '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'int' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'int' objects>, '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'int' objects>, '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'int' objects>, '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'int' objects>, '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'int' objects>, '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'int' objects>, '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'int' objects>, '__add__': <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'int' objects>, '__radd__': <slot wrapper '__radd__' of 'int' objects>, '__sub__': <slot wrapper '__sub__' of 'int' objects>, '__rsub__': <slot wrapper '__rsub__' of 'int' objects>, '__mul__': <slot wrapper '__mul__' of 'int' objects>, '__rmul__': <slot wrapper '__rmul__' of 'int' objects>, '__mod__': <slot wrapper '__mod__' of 'int' objects>, '__rmod__': <slot wrapper '__rmod__' of 'int' objects>, '__divmod__': <slot wrapper '__divmod__' of 'int' objects>, '__rdivmod__': <slot wrapper '__rdivmod__' of 'int' objects>, '__pow__': <slot wrapper '__pow__' of 'int' objects>, '__rpow__': <slot wrapper '__rpow__' of 'int' objects>, '__neg__': <slot wrapper '__neg__' of 'int' objects>, '__pos__': <slot wrapper '__pos__' of 'int' objects>, '__abs__': <slot wrapper '__abs__' of 'int' objects>, '__bool__': <slot wrapper '__bool__' of 'int' objects>, '__invert__': <slot wrapper '__invert__' of 'int' objects>, '__lshift__': <slot wrapper '__lshift__' of 'int' objects>, '__rlshift__': <slot wrapper '__rlshift__' of 'int' objects>, '__rshift__': <slot wrapper '__rshift__' of 'int' objects>, '__rrshift__': <slot wrapper '__rrshift__' of 'int' objects>, '__and__': <slot wrapper '__and__' of 'int' objects>, '__rand__': <slot wrapper '__rand__' of 'int' objects>, '__xor__': <slot wrapper '__xor__' of 'int' objects>, '__rxor__': <slot wrapper '__rxor__' of 'int' objects>, '__or__': <slot wrapper '__or__' of 'int' objects>, '__ror__': <slot wrapper '__ror__' of 'int' objects>, '__int__': <slot wrapper '__int__' of 'int' objects>, '__float__': <slot wrapper '__float__' of 'int' objects>, '__floordiv__': <slot wrapper '__floordiv__' of 'int' objects>, '__rfloordiv__': <slot wrapper '__rfloordiv__' of 'int' objects>, '__truediv__': <slot wrapper '__truediv__' of 'int' objects>, '__rtruediv__': <slot wrapper '__rtruediv__' of 'int' objects>, '__index__': <slot wrapper '__index__' of 'int' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x102eb7630>, 'conjugate': <method 'conjugate' of 'int' objects>, 'bit_length': <method 'bit_length' of 'int' objects>, 'to_bytes': <method 'to_bytes' of 'int' objects>, 'from_bytes': <method 'from_bytes' of 'int' objects>, '__trunc__': <method '__trunc__' of 'int' objects>, '__floor__': <method '__floor__' of 'int' objects>, '__ceil__': <method '__ceil__' of 'int' objects>, '__round__': <method '__round__' of 'int' objects>, '__getnewargs__': <method '__getnewargs__' of 'int' objects>, '__format__': <method '__format__' of 'int' objects>, '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'int' objects>, 'real': <attribute 'real' of 'int' objects>, 'imag': <attribute 'imag' of 'int' objects>, 'numerator': <attribute 'numerator' of 'int' objects>, 'denominator': <attribute 'denominator' of 'int' objects>, '__doc__': "int(x=0) -> integer\nint(x, base=10) -> integer\n\nConvert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments\nare given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point\nnumbers, this truncates towards zero.\n\nIf x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,\nbytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the\ngiven base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded\nby whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.\nBase 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.\n>>> int('0b100', base=0)\n4"}
int(x=0) -> integer
int(x, base=10) -> integer

Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
numbers, this truncates towards zero.

If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
>>> int('0b100', base=0)
4
```

A better code would be the following:

```
for attrib in ['name', 'str', 'repr', 'dict', 'doc']:
     print(getattr(int, '__%s__' % attrib))
```

The output of this code is identical to that of the previous code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my teacher said you can use them with objects and functions. 
After I tried what you wrote, I got an output (int). So that is all ? What is the point?

Comment: OK, now I got it and I think I know who to use them, but instead I could just use str(x) right ? Thanks again. appreciated!!!!

Comment: @iCoder Indeed, you can use `str(x)` if you want a string representation of your integer object. I think the point of your teacher was that you can inherit these "magic" methods (`__name__`, `__repr__`, etc.) from the `int` class to your subclasses,  and modify their behaviour. And yes, you can use them with functions (but not necessarily with function calls).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a class:

```
class ClassName:
    '''docstring:Class help information can be viewed through 
    classname.__doc__''' 
    print(ClassName.__doc__)

    print(ClassName.__name__)
    #print classname

    print(ClassName.__dict__)
    #print field by dict
```

**str**、**repr** just like **init**,They're all basic overload methods

```
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector (%d, %d)' % (self.a, self.b)
    #Used to convert a value into a form suitable for human reading
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean I want to do the same thing for a function not for a class. I tried but I am getting an error. I want to print the function doc, dict ...etc

Comment: @iCoder I'm sorry I didn't answer the question correctly.